# What is an example of a manifold that is not smooth?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Could someone provide an example of a manifold that is not smooth? All manifolds that come to mind are smooth! By a manifold, I mean a Hausdorff, second countable, locally Euclidean space.

Comment: Consider http://math.stackexchange.com/q/408221

Comment: You need to clarify what you want: A topological manifold not homeomorphic to a smooth one? Or non-smooth submanifold of a Euclidean space? The first one is hard, the second is trivial.

Comment: I seek a manifold that is not homeomorphic to a smooth manifold. Apparently, from what I am seeing, this is not as simple as I had thought. Is the E_8 the "simplest" such manifold?

Comment: @user111970: Depends on your definition of "simplest". Dimension-wise, it is the smallest. But description-wise, there is a big black hole in its description, which is Freedman's works (Casson handles and such); in this sense, E8 is not even an explicit example (its homotopy type though is explicit).

Answer (score 8):

In light of OP's response, here is a construction borrowed from my class notes. However, to show that this manifold does not admit any smooth structure will not be discussed in my answer. The interested reader is welcome to check the other class [note](http://www.math.binghamton.edu/somnath/Notes/TST-TF.pdf) taken by Prof. Somanth Basu.

Kervaire claimed that there exists a ten dimensional closed topological manifold which does not support any smooth structure $K^{10}$. In terms of embedding, this means that although by a slight modification of above argument, $K^{10}$ can be topologically embedded into a subset of Euclidean space. There does not exist a smooth submanifold, $M^{10}\subset R^{m}$ such that $M^{10}\cong K^{10}$ homeomorphically. In particular we cannot define a tangent plane globally.

Consider a triangle, which is a topological manifold that is homeomorphic to the circle but not differeomorphic as it has corners. And so is a pentagon. For the $K^{10}$ example, if I remove a point it would be smoothable.

Kervaire's example admits the following relation:
$$
H_{*}(K^{10})=H_{*}(\mathbb{S}^{5}\times \mathbb{S}^{2})
$$

We try to approach this by considering $\mathbb{S}^{1}\times \mathbb{S}^{1}-\mathbb{D}^{2}$. I claim that this is homotopically equivalent to 
$$
\mathbb{S}^{1}\wedge \mathbb{S}^{1}
$$
And I can prove this by gluing two annulus orthogonally, if I fill in a disk it would become a torus. Similarly we can consider $\mathbb{S}^{5}\times \mathbb{S}^{5}-\mathbb{D}^{10}$. This would be the same as 
$$
\epsilon^{5}_{\mathbb{S}^{5}}=\mathbb{S}^{5}\times \mathbb{D}^{5}\cup \mathbb{S}^{5}\times \mathbb{D}^{5}
$$
such that we map it by
$$
\mathbb{D}^{5}\times \mathbb{D}^{5}\rightarrow \mathbb{D}^{5}\times \mathbb{D}^{5}:(x,y)\rightarrow (y,x)
$$
We now cinsider a more general case in which one bundle is the disk bundle of dimension $5$ over the sphere. Another candidate we may consider is the tangent bundle. Since $\mathbb{D}^{5}\subset \mathbb{S}^{5}$, we have
$$
N^{10}=\mathbb{DTS}^{5}\bigcup \mathbb{DTS}^{5}
$$
where we glue the two disk subbundles 
$$
\mathbb{D}^{5}\times \mathbb{D}^{5}\rightarrow \mathbb{D}^{5}\times \mathbb{D}^{5}
$$
We can claim that the boundary of $N^{10}$ is homeomorphic $\mathbb{S}^{9}$. We know that ananlogous to $n=1$ case we have
$$
N^{10}\sim \mathbb{S}^{5}\mathbb{S}^{5}
$$
Then we have
$$
H_{*}(\partial N)=H_{*}(\mathbb{S}^{9})
$$
by long exact sequence of homology.

Then by Whitehead's theorem we can prove that they are homotopically, and by Smale's theorem we can show that
$$
\partial N\cong \mathbb{S}^{9}
$$
homeomorphically. After filling a disk $\mathbb{D}^{10}$, we call
$$
K^{10}=N^{10}\cup \mathbb{D}^{10}
$$
It now took some effort to show that this bundle has no smooth structure.

**Remark** The long exact sequence in homology calculation only works for $n$ is odd dimensional, for $n=8$ this would fail.

Comment: But these a topological manifolds that *can be given* a smooth structure.

Comment: @ZevChonoles: I think this (manifolds with no smooth structure) is not what the OP wanted, though.

Comment: @user32240: You might be right, but let's hear from the OP (hopefully).

Comment: Sorry about the late response! The square and triangle can be given a smooth structure. What I meant by a "manifold not being smooth" is a manifold that cannot be given a smooth structure. The E_8 manifold is what I was looking for.

Comment: @user111970: I see. I shall update.

Comment: Let me try to be as clear as possible. From what I understand, a smooth manifold is a hausdorff, second countable space with atlas {(U_i, f_i)} where the corresponding transition maps g_ij are smooth maps. What I seek is a manifold M with atlas where the transition maps are not smooth.

Comment: @user111970: updated.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little research gave an answer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Relationship_with_topological_manifolds.

Also, most people cannot think in dimension $\geq 4$, so that explains why you couldn't think of a non-smoothable manifold.

Comment: I would say that this is not the real reason, but the fact that constructions and obstructions to smoothability are quite subtle. I would bet, Poincare was as good in higher dimensional imagination as anybody else, but he could not have come up with, say, E8 example (which required 2 Fields medals and a lot of prior developments in math and physics).