# Example of a $C^k$-homeomorphism $h : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ whose inverse is $C^{k-1}$, but not $C^k$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$C^k$ stands for $k$-times continuously differentiable ($k = \infty$ is included). The map $h : \mathbb R \to  \mathbb R, h(x) = x^3$, is the standard example of a $C^\infty$-homeomorphism whose inverse is not even differentiable.

> For $k < \infty$, does there exist a $C^k$-homeomorphism $h : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ whose inverse is $C^{k-1}$, but not $C^k$?

This seems to be a quite obvious question, but for $k > 1$ I did neither find any example in the literature nor via internet search. My own efforts were unsuccessful, candidates as $h(x) = x^n$ do not work.

Bonus question:

> For $k < \infty$, does there exist a $C^\infty$-homeomorphism $h : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ whose inverse is $C^{k-1}$, but not $C^k$?

Comment: What about $\dfrac{x^3}{3}+x$?

Comment: @Darsen For which $k$?

Comment: $f(x)=\dfrac{x^3}{3}+x$ is clearly $C^\infty$. Now, $f'(x)=x^2+1$ is never $0$, so by the Inverse Function Theorem $f$ has a continuously differentiable inverse. However, $f''(x)=2x$ is $0$ at $x=0$, so if the inverse had second derivative, it would have to be infinity there. Therefore, the inverse is $C^1$, but not $C^2$.

Comment: If $f$ is $C^k$ and $f^{-1}$ is differentiable, then $(f^{-1})^{\prime}(x)=1/f^{\prime}(f^{-1}(x))$, so $f^{-1}$ will  be $C^k$ as well. What am I missing?

Comment: @Thorgott Ah, you are right. You should give an official answer.

Comment: @Thorgott But you need your function and its derivatives to not be zero.

Comment: The derivative is non-zero by the chain rule since $1=\operatorname{id}^{\prime}(x)=(f^{-1}\circ f)^{\prime}(x)=(f^{-1})^{\prime}(f(x))f^{\prime}(x)$. I don't see the issue with the function being $0$ (it has to be at one point, anyhow).

Comment: You're right. I meant to say nonzero first derivative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $k>1$, there is no such map. The reason is that if $f\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a $C^k$-bijection with differentiable inverse, then the inverse is automatically $C^k$. This can be seen as a special instance of the inverse function theorem. If $f^{-1}$ is differentiable, this dictates we have $(f^{-1})^{\prime}(x)=1/f^{\prime}(f^{-1}(x))$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. As composition of continuous functions, $(f^{-1})^{\prime}$ is continuous, so $f^{-1}$ is $C^1$. Then, as composition of $C^1$-functions, $(f^{-1})^{\prime}$ is $C^1$, hence $f^{-1}$ is $C^2$. Induction carries us all the way to $f^{-1}$ being $C^k$.