# manifolds without symplicial or cell structure

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

In many situations in topology, (like the poincare duality) they put a distinction between the space being a manifold or just a cell or simplicial complex. I want to know why this is important, in other words are there manifolds without the latter structure?

Comment: Every manifold is homotopy equivalent to a cell complex, but not necessarily homeomorphic to one. Is it what you wanted to know?

Comment: I need to know an example of a manifold(smooth or topological) which is not homeomorphic to a cell complex.

Comment: There are no smooth examples. 4-manifold called E8 is a topological example.

Answer (score 3):

A homeomorphism from a manifold to a simplicial complex is called a *triangularization*.  The [$E_8$ manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_manifold) (a four-dimensional manifold) does not have a triangularization.  I don't know the history of this result but I suspect it's from the late 80s as the proof uses Casson's invariant.

More recently -- just over a year ago! -- Ciprian Manolescu proved that there are manifolds of any dimension greater than 4 which do not admit an triangularization.  He uses Pin(2)-equivariant Seiberg-Witten Floer homology.  [Here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.2354) is the paper.

Comment: Smooth manifolds *are* triangularizable, though. The question does not make it too clear whether it is using *manifold* to mean smooth or topological manifolds.

Comment: The proof does not use Casson's invariant, the first proof of non-smoothability used Donaldson's invariants (1983); one can now prove it easier using Seiberg-Witten invariants. Of course, existence of E8 manifolds requires Freedman's work (1982).

Comment: @studiosus Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Is it not possible to make a topological manifold smooth? so that a triangulization for a smooth manifold gives one for a topological manifold?

Comment: @7779052: Not every topological manifold is smoothable. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408221 for a detailed discussion.