# Is the E8 manifold homeomorphic to a CW complex?

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology

Is the E8 manifold homeomorphic to a CW complex? (I know that it is not triangulable)

**Edit:** The [E8 manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_manifold) is the unique compact (without boundary), simply connected topological 4-manifold, whose 2nd integer homology (equipped with its intersection form) is isomorphic to the $E_8$ lattice. A detailed description of this manifold can be found in an answer to [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408221/the-easiest-non-smoothable-manifold/781507#781507).

It appears to be an open problem to determine if every $n$-dimensional topological manifold admits structure of a CW complex. Positive answer (due to hard work of many people, most importantly - Kirby and Siebenmann for $n\ge 6$, Freedman and Quinn for $n=5$) is known in all dimensions except for $n=4$. Furthermore, all connected noncompact 4-dimensional manifolds are known to be triangulable (this is due to Quinn) and, hence, the answer is positive in this case as well.

Given that the E8-manifold is, in some sense, the simplest nonsmoothable 4-dimensional manifold, it makes sense to ask if it is homeomorphic to a CW complex.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed... What exactly is not clear?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Apparently everything after the first line was only just added. But the first line itself is all that's necessary, so the question remains...

Comment: My guess is that the closers did not know what E8 is. The notion is standard in topology but might confuse somebody familiar only with, say, Lie groups.

Comment: Too bad it was closed. Given the tags, I thought that the question was clear enough. If I understand correctly, the answer isn't known!?

Comment: @Lepanais: Yes, it is an open problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think, we can safely treat Andrew Ranicky as an expert in these matters. In a comment to his answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7921/failure-of-smoothing-theory-for-topological-4-manifolds) Ranicky asked the following:

**Question**. Is it true that a 4-dimensional manifold $X$ admits a CW-complex structure if and only if $X$ is smoothable?

Since the E8-manifold is not smoothable, your question is a special case of an open (and, I guess, important) problem in 4-dimensional topology.