# Topological manifold but not "smooth"

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, examples-counterexamples, smooth-manifolds

I would like to know if there are examples of topological manifolds that not admit  a smooth atlas, or more generally a differentiable structure of class $C^k$ for $k\geq1$.
In the book "**Introduction to Manifolds** - Loring W. Tu"" the author says that an example of this type is dued to M. Kervaire.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408221/the-easiest-non-smoothable-manifold

Comment: For the sake of completeness, all topological manifolds of dimension at most $3$ admit a unique smooth stiffening.

Comment: Your second question is actually not more general. A manifold that admits a $C^1$ structure admits an essentially unique compatible $C^\infty$ (even $C^\omega$, analytic) structure.