# Is every open topological $n$-manifold homeomorphic to a CW complex? $(n \geq 5)$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, cw-complexes

The question of whether a closed topological manifold admits a CW structure is well-understood (with positive answer) for $n  \neq 4$, thanks to the work  Quinn ($n=5$) and Kirby-Siebenmann $(n >5)$.

However I cannot find anything about open (non-compact without boundary) manifolds of dimension $n\geq 5$. At least for $n \leq 4$ the answer is known to be yes (trivial for $n \leq 3$ and work of Quinn for $n=4$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/869280/386744).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not understand why people restrict to closed manifolds in their MSE/MO answers. If you look at the original papers, you will find no such restrictions. Moreover, the result (existence of a handle decomposition) also holds for manifolds with boundary and, furthermore, its proven that one can extend the given handle decomposition on a (locally flat) submanifold to the entire manifold:

1. In dimension $\ge 6$ this is in the book by Kirby and Siebenmann, page 104, Theorem 2.1:

*Kirby, Robion C.; Siebenmann, Laurence C.*, [**Foundational essays on topological manifolds, smoothings and triangulations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/9781400881505), Annals of Mathematics Studies, 88. Princeton, N.J.: Princeton University Press and University of Tokyo Press. V, 355 p. (1977). [ZBL0361.57004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0361.57004).

2. In dimension 5, this is due to Quinn, Theorem 2.3.1 in

*Quinn, Frank*, [**Ends of maps. III: Dimensions 4 and 5**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1214437139), J. Differ. Geom. 17, 503-521 (1982). [ZBL0533.57009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0533.57009).

Comment: As a side note: this difference between open and closed manifolds is important for $n=4$. As Moishe pointed out in this MSE answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2238453/386744), Quinn shows in that same paper that every open 4-manifold is smoothable and then has a CW structure (actually a triangulation). For closed 4-manifolds this is an open question.