# Does every manifold admit a CW structure?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Basically the question above. Does any topological manifold admit a CW -structure?

If not, what assumptions make this a true statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is every open topological $n$-manifold homeomorphic to a CW complex? $(n \geq 5)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4348580/is-every-open-topological-n-manifold-homeomorphic-to-a-cw-complex-n-geq-5) Generally yes for dim $\neq 4$, while for dim $4$ it is an open problem AFAIK.