# Give me an example of a topological manifold which is not a smooth manifold.

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I was just wondering whether someone could give me an example of a topological manifold which is not a smooth manifold. In particular, I want an example of a topological manifold where no differentiable structure could be given.

I have thought a lot but in vain. If someone could put some light it would be of great help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **Theorem.** Any topological manifold of dimension $2$ or $3$ can be endowed with a real analytic manifold structure. Furthermore, two such structures which are homeomorphic are $C^\omega$-diffeomorphic.

**Proof.** See *Geometric topology in dimension $2$ and $3$* by E. Moise. $\Box$

Therefore, an example must have dimension at least $4$, such a construction is not easy, see for example the article *[A manifold which does not admit any differentiable structure](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kervarf.pdf)* by M. Kervaire.

Comment: What about dimension 1?  [Honest question.]

Comment: @Randall Any connected topological manifold (without boundary) of dimension $1$ is either homeomorphic to the real line or the unit circle and both of them can be endowed with a real analytic manifold structure, so the theorem also holds true in dimension $1$! I didn't mention it because it is a less deep result, but this is a good question! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can see the example of Kervaire
[The "Easiest" non-smoothable manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408221/the-easiest-non-smoothable-manifold)

Comment: As a topological space this is homeomorphic to the real line, so can be "given a differentiable structure" that respects the topology. I think the question is unclear.