# Smoothing non-differentiable manifolds?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

i recently started studying differential topology and smooth manifolds. I'm really new to this area but a frequent question that came to my mind quite often is the following

> consider a topological manifold $M$ that is not smooth (maybe lots of sharp edges on its surface). Are there any ways to "smoothen" such manifolds such that they become differentiable at every point ? If the answer is yes, under what circumstances i.e. what are the requirements for $M$ and how can this be done?

I already figured out that if $X$ is a topological space, $Y$ a differentiable manifold and there is a homeomorphism $$ \phi:X \to Y$$ $X$ can be equipped with a differentiable structure.

However, is there more to discover? I really do not know what exactly to search for or what books i should look for.

I highly appreciate any suggestion about keywords/theorems or preferably books that cover similar topics.

Thank you very much.

Comment: [This](http://people.virginia.edu/~mah7cd/Conferences/Vietnam2013/kervarf.pdf) paper by Kervaire shows the existence of a topological manifold which does not admit any differentiable structure. I am not familiar  however with sufficient conditions for a topological manifold to admit a differentiable structure. Maybe someone more experienced can answer this.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408221/the-easiest-non-smoothable-manifold). [This paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/96b6/19b697a6f46ee495c9481406257ff1edf555.pdf) gives non-smoothable homology classes in a Grassmannian.

Comment: thanks for both of your suggestions. highly appreciating it! to both of you :-)